# suppress Mac Retina @2x calls

Tags: javascript, sapui5, retina-display

I have a web application developed using SAPUI5. We are fetching some images from backend and displaying the same on Front End.

I am making an ajax call to .net webservice. This webservice returns me URL of images I am showing in my web app. Now, for Mac retina devices, browser is automatically adding @2 to images. For ex. My Image url is https:/servername:port/imagepath/default.png. For retina devices its calling https:/servername:port/imagepath/default@2.png

We do not have any default@2.png images in server side. And we cannot add these images as well. The problem is its taking lot of time to search @2 images and sends 500 error.

Is there any way I can disable this and force browser to not make @2 calls?

Thanks,
Parth Jhalani

Comment: Sounds like a "SAPUI5" setting. Web pages do not normally request separate graphics for retina displays, so that must be some part of the framework you are using.

Comment: Please consider accepting the below answer to let others know that this issue is resolved. Simply control the `densityAware` property.

Answer (score 1):

The `sap.m.Image` control automatically chooses the right density, depending on the device on which it is displayed. If an image of a certain density is not available, the image control falls back to a default image, which should be provided as well.

Example:

```js
new Image({ // required from "sap/m/Image"
  // ...,
  densityAware: false,
});
```

From the [API reference of `sap/m/Image`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Image):

> If property `densityAware` is `true`, a density-specific image will be loaded by constructing a density-specific image name in format `[imageName]@[densityValue].[extension]` from the given `src` and the devicePixelRatio of the current device. The only supported density values are `1`, `1.5` and `2`. If the original devicePixelRatio ratio isn't one of the three valid numbers, it will be rounded to the nearest one.

> If this is set to true, one or more network requests will be made that try to obtain the density perfect version of the image.
>
> By default, this is set to false, so the `src` image is loaded directly without attempting to fetch the density perfect image for high-density devices.
>
> **Note:** Before 1.60, the default value was set to true, which brought redundant network requests for apps that used the default but did not provide density perfect image versions on server-side. You should set this property to true **only if** you also provide the corresponding image versions for high-density devices.

This will help you to avoid unnecessary file@2.png calls.